# Set value to an array in pentaho javascript step

Tags: javascript, arrays, pentaho, pentaho-spoon

i have some values in the input and i want to save them into an array but first i want to set the "0" index of the array to 0 and then in the 1,2,3,4 indexs add the value of the input but i can get to make it

before to set the values of the input i set the 0 to the position 0 of the array but it doesnt work

the thing is that i want to use only the first four number of the input_data into an array but first set the 0 position to 0 and then add 5,10,15,20.
so the final array would be 0,5,10,15,20

i set the index "0" of the array to 0 and the other indexes i fill them whit the incoming data.

Comment: Are those values in the string format like 1,2,3,4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on how the data is reaching the 'Modified Java Script Value' step.
If it is one single row, with the string containing a "CSV", then Rohit.007 answer will suffice.

If you have multiple rows reaching the step, **the Script will Repeat N(row) times**. If you have 4 rows being fed to the step, this script will run 4 times, so you need some sort of restraint on the Variables, so you don't repeat some parts of the code.

Personally i would use something like this for Pentaho:
[image]

I generated 4 rows, with an add sequence , 1 to 4.
The first run of the script creates the array, pushes 0 and the value of the first row. The other iterations of the script just keep pushing whatever values are found on the specified row to this array (without "Re-declaring" it).

Remenber that the "For Each" command is kind of blurred in pentaho, since you're almost always dealing with multi-row tables, so whatever you do in scripts has to have some constraints on variables declarations.

Comment: thanks Cristian, your solution worked.. i just had to declare a variable whit the rows count to access to each index dinamically and be able to do what i want THANKS AGAIN ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code.

```js
let array = [];

array.push(0);

let string = '1,2,3,4';
array = array.concat(string.split(','));
let result = array.map(function (x) { 
  return parseInt(x, 10); 
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but like cristian said i forgot to specify the type of the incoming data, it was per row, no in one string but thanks again for your answer